# How to resolve this problem? How to break the grid row, bootstrap 4? Which Bootstrap classes I have to use?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

4. Test Links.
   Using Bootstrap classes, modify the div element with the id "links" so that on extra small
   resolutions (<576px), each link and ad takes one whole row. It should look like this:
   [image]

On small resolutions and higher (≥576px), both links should take one half of the row and the ads
should be invisible. It should look like this:
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tests</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      a,
      div {
        outline: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="links">
      <a href="#">Aptitude tests</a>
      <div>Ads!</div>
      <a href="#">Programming tests</a>
      <div>More ads!</div>
    </div>
    <article>Here you can find various tests...</article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework question (based on it being point number 4  without having 1-3 :) ) The guidelines are to help you get to the answer rather than giving you the full code, so here's a pointer where to start that has good examples also: [Bootstrap Grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)... give that a go and let us know how far you get with it. If you run into any problems, let us know what they are so we can help you with those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting close with your answer. To get it to work, these are the changes you need to make to the original code in your question:

1. add the class `row` to the container that has your cols (i.e. the `links` div) - cols must be in a row
2. Add `col-12 col-sm-6` to the `a` elements (you just had the wrong breakpoint when you said `col-12 col-md-6`) Ref: [Bootstrap breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options), [Bootstrap Grid Mix & Match Col classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match)
3. For the `div`s, add `d-sm-none` to hide it on small screens (Ref: [Bootstrap Display property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)) and `col-12` to show it full width on all other screens.

You can see it working here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <style>
      a, div {
        outline: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="links" class="row">
      <a href="#" class="col-12 col-sm-6">Aptitude tests</a>
      <div class="d-sm-none col-12">Ads!</div>
      <a href="#" class="col-12 col-sm-6">Programming tests</a>
      <div  class="d-sm-none col-12">More ads!</div>
    </div>
    <article>Here you can find various tests...</article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still learned something new, it was useful to be involved and help. If necessary, I will ask you again on other issues. FluffyKitten :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Tests</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <style>
            a, div {
                outline: 1px solid black;
            }
            @media (min-width: 576px ) {
                #links {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    padding-right: none;
                    padding-left: none;
                }
            }

            @media (max-width: 576px ) {
                #links {
                    flex-direction: row;
                }
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="links">
            <a href="#" class="col-12">Aptitude tests</a>
            <div class="d-none d-md-block">Ads!</div>
            <a href="#" class="col-12">Programming tests</a>
            <div class="d-none d-md-block">More ads!</div>
        </div>
        <article>Here you can find various tests...</article>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code I got with it.

Comment: Good start! Now you just need to get the columns to change size at a breakpoint. Take a look at the [Mix and Match section of the Bootstrap Grid page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match) and see if you can work out how to do that. The description in this part might not be great, but see what youy can do and let me know if you get stuff by commenting using @fluffykitten so it lets me know you've tagged me

Comment: I can't think of a way to make the two columns: "Aptitude tests" and "Programming tests" stand side by side with the same width.  I gave them these classes: class="col-12 col-md-6". I read the article, but it was not very clear to me to solve my problem specifically. I am the last question from this interview question (https://www.testdome.com/d/bootstrap-interview-questions/10?a=true), the others I did without a problem so far. @fluffykitten